Google generativeai Kivy Andriod app crach at launch due to grpc
I am building a kivy app with integration of google-generativeai. I used buildozer to compile for Android. The compilation was successful but the app crashed when launching.
Error:
07-08 19:33:51.220 23213 23416 I python  :    File "/home/xxx/xxxApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/xxxapp/arm64-v8a/grpc/init.py", line 22, in 
07-08 19:33:51.221 23213 23416 I python  :    File "/home/xxx/xxxApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/xxxapp/arm64-v8a/grpc/_compression.py", line 20, in 
07-08 19:33:51.221 23213 23416 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.xxx.xxxapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
07-08 19:33:51.221 23213 23416 I python  : Python for android ended.
My requirements in buildozer.spec:
python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.0.2,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow==10.0.0,Markdown==3.6,requests,charset-normalizer==2.1.1,gtts,urllib3,chardet,idna,ffpyplayer,google-generativeai==0.5.0,certifi,typing_extensions,google-ai-generativelanguage==0.6.6,google-api-core==2.19.1,grpcio,googleapis-common-protos,protobuf

My questions are - did anyone try build a google-generativeai kivy app for Andriod using buildozer compilation before? Does buildozer support google-generativeai library? It looks like from the error grpc library has no recipe for AARCH64 architecture, is there any other way to get around this? Thanks.

After researching for days, according to github, they didn't have the recipe compatible with Aarch64 architecture. I changed to Openai library. It worked. Although openai api is not free, I chose a low cost model. This is requirements if anyone comes across openai.
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.0.2,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow==10.0.0,openai,requests,charset-normalizer==2.1.1,gtts,urllib3,chardet,idna,ffpyplayer,certifi,typing_extensions,aiohttp,pydantic==1.10.2,httpx,sniffio,httpcore,h11,tqdm,regex,rfc3986,anyio,exceptiongroup,distro

